# Issue in implementing 64-bit binary number multiplication in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a code in LISP to multiply two 64-bit numbers.
Using SBCL on ubuntu platform to compile program.
My algorithm is as follows.

1) Convert first number into 64-bit binary representation.

2) Perform binary addition of first number with itself second number of times.

I wrote following function to convert decimal number into binary (takes decimal number & empty list as parameter)

```
(defun bin (N B) 
(cond
((= N 0) B)
((evenp N)(bin (round (/ N 2)) (cons 0 B)))
((oddp N) (bin (floor (/ N 2))  (cons 1 B)))    
))
```

Following function to to perform binary addition.( takes nos of bits, initial carry, first binary no, second binary no, empty list)

```
 (defun addbin (n carry L1 L2 L3)
 (cond
((< n 0) (cons carry L3))
((and (= (lastE L1 n) 0) (= (lastE L2 n) 0) (= carry 0)) (addbin (- n 1) 0  L1 L2 (cons 0 L3)))
((and (= (lastE L1 n) 0) (= (lastE L2 n) 0) (= carry 1)) (addbin (- n 1) 0  L1 L2 (cons 1 L3)))
((and (= (lastE L1 n) 0) (= (lastE L2 n) 1) (= carry 0)) (addbin (- n 1) 0 L1 L2 (cons 1 L3)))
((and (= (lastE L1 n) 0) (= (lastE L2 n) 1) (= carry 1)) (addbin (- n 1) 1 L1 L2 (cons 0 L3)))
((and (= (lastE L1 n) 1) (= (lastE L2 n) 0) (= carry 0)) (addbin (- n 1) 0 L1 L2 (cons 1 L3)))
((and (= (lastE L1 n) 1) (= (lastE L2 n) 0) (= carry 1)) (addbin (- n 1) 1 L1 L2 (cons 0 L3)))
((and (= (lastE L1 n) 1) (= (lastE L2 n) 1) (= carry 0)) (addbin (- n 1) 1 L1 L2 (cons 0 L3)))
((and (= (lastE L1 n) 1) (= (lastE L2 n) 1) (= carry 1)) (addbin (- n 1) 1 L1 L2 (cons 1 L3)))
))
```

supplementary function to return nth bit in binary number is (takes list & n)

```
(defun lastE (L n)
(cond
((= n 0) (first L))
(t (lastE (rest L) (- n 1)))
))
```

and multiplication function as

```
(defun bin_mult(nA A B)
(cond
    ((= B 1) A)
    (t (bin_mult  (addbin (- (length A) 1) 0 A nA ()) A (- B 1)))
 ))
```

and I am executing following piece of code to perform multiplication

```
(print "Enter two numbers to be multiplied")
(finish-output nil)
(defvar num1)
(defvar num2)
(defvar a)

(setq num1 (read))
(setq num2 (read))
(setq a (bin num1 ()))


(defvar cnt)
(setq cnt (integer-length num1))
(print cnt)
(dotimes (i (- 63 cnt))
(push 0 a)
)

(print "First number in binary format is" )
(print a)
(print "Multiplication two numbers with concurrency is")

(print (bin_mult a a num2))
```

I am getting following output (for 10*4)

```
(1 0 1 0)
```

I tried tracing the execution of bin_mult function on command prompt.
I am getting following output for (trace bin_mult x x 4) where x is (1 0 1 0)

```
(bin_mult x x 4)
  0: (BIN_MULT (1 0 1 0) (1 0 1 0) 4)
    1: (BIN_MULT (1 0 1 0 0) (1 0 1 0) 3)
      2: (BIN_MULT (1 0 1 0 0) (1 0 1 0) 2)
       3: (BIN_MULT (1 0 1 0 0) (1 0 1 0) 1)
       3: BIN_MULT returned (1 0 1 0)
     2: BIN_MULT returned (1 0 1 0)
   1: BIN_MULT returned (1 0 1 0)
  0: BIN_MULT returned (1 0 1 0)
 (1 0 1 0)
```

Somehow intermediate results are not getting added.
Kindly help in resolving bug in this piece of code..

Thank you..

Comment: I haven't looked into the code much yet, but some notes regarding it: 1) You should use the standard naming conventions (lowercase, words separated with a dash) instead of the very inconsistent mix of styles you have at the moment (`bin_mult` has an underscore, `lastE` is camelcase and `addbin` is all together (and the order is reverse to `bin_mult`); variables are a mix of upper- and lowercase). 2) The names themselves should be more descriptive (notice how you had to explain what all the function arguments are). 3) Lists are pretty inefficient; you should probably use bit-vectors instead.

Comment: @jkiiski: Regarding efficiency, one should perhaps just use `*` (;-).

Comment: @svante If the purpose is to play around with various ways of doing bignum operations, bit-vectors sounds like a better approach than lists, while making "use the built-in bignums" rather contra-productive.

Comment: The code formatting is making it really hard to see what's going on. It would probably be to the benefit of everyone if you properly indent. Worst case, I will try to remember doing that for you tomorrow, when I have a bit more time for large-scale edits.

Comment: Without correct indentation and formatting, developing in any programming language is a pain. Lisp is no different. Please take the time to improve your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you can just do the multiplication and simulate overflow later.

```lisp
(defun multiply-overflow (bits &rest xs)
  (let ((result (reduce #'* xs :initial-value 1)))
    (multiple-value-bind (_ remainder) (floor result (1- (ash 1 bits)))
      remainder)))

(multiply-overflow 64 1000000000000 1000000000000)
; ==> 2003764205206950850
```